# Extracting all numbers in a string that are surrounded by a certain pattern in R

Tags: r, regex

I'd like to extract all numbers in a string that are flanked by two markers/patterns. However, regular expressions in R are my bane.

I have something like this:

```
string  <- "<img src='images/stimuli/32.png' style='width:341.38790035587186px;height: 265px;'><img src='images/stimuli/36.png' style='width:341.38790035587186px;height: 265px;'>"
marker1 <- "images/stimuli/"
marker2 <- ".png"
```

and want something like this

```
gsub(paste0(".*", marker1, "*(.*?) *", marker2, ".*"), "\\1", string)

[1] "32" "36"
```

However I get this:

```
[1] "32"
```

PS If someone has a good guide to understand how regular expressions work here, please let me know. I am pretty sure that the answer is pretty simple but I just don't get regex :(

Comment: Yes, i'd like all numbers that are surrounded by the markers as vector of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
string  <- "<img src='images/stimuli/32.png' style='width:341.38790035587186px;height: 265px;'><img src='images/stimuli/36.png' style='width:341.38790035587186px;height: 265px;'>"
regmatches(string, gregexpr("images/stimuli/\\K\\d+(?=\\.png)", string, perl=TRUE))[[1]]
# => [1] "32" "36"
```

**NOTE**: If there can be anything, not just numbers, you may replace `\\d+` with `.*?`.

See the [R demo](https://tio.run/##nVC7DoIwANz5iqZLISqvykMEnZzcjE6UgUBTGikhbY349QgaFxMXx7vcKyfHUWnJOwZAugIw5YIBJasMcVEyqhylubi13MG@3XcMAaUfLc3Qnde6SfDas3EcbVwXB0EceXHYD9uGctboBPhhMCG0@x0Z/hsJDUmZKHXVUGW@5y8Bmzg69NKEXz2EHAmpF@Y@I2RutOASfEw9lW12Pl0OlpXnXlEYopRXKv3XGbMYGuP4BA) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KyMpPh/1).

The `regmatches` with `gregexpr` extract all matches found in the input.

The regex matches:

- `images/stimuli/` - a literal string
- `\K` - a match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?=\.png)` - a `.png` substring (`.` is a special character, it needs escaping).

Comment: I never knew about the `\K` operator. Neat!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_extract` from the package `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(string, "(?<=images/stimuli/)\\d+(?=\\.png)")
[[1]]
[1] "32" "36"
```

This solution uses positive lookbehind, `(?<=images/stimuli/)`, and positive lookahead, `(?=\\.png)`, which are both non-capturing groups, and instead matches one or more numbers, `\\d+`, sitting between the two.